# ¿Cómo quitar las sombras a una Action Bar?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, toolbar

Quiero hacer una Action Bar o toolbar a la cual no se le vean las sombras, sí cambio a android.widget.toolbar ya no se ven, pero no se infla el menú. 
Quiero obtener algo similar a la imagen.

[image: Toolbar]

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Brandon, agrega tu código para que sea de utilidad tu pregunta a la comunidad, revisar [ask], saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La sombra indica que se tiene cierta elevación,

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

en este caso puedes usar la propiedad  [setElevation(...)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActionBar.html#setElevation(float)), define 0 pixeles de elevación:

```
   toolbar.setElevation(0)
```

Ejemplo:

```
ActionBar toolbar = getSupportActionBar();
toolbar.setElevation(0)
```

también puedes definir directamente esta propiedad directamente en el widget :

```
 <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
      android:id="@+id/toolbar" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"

      android:elevation="0dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Definiendo la propiedad:

```
app:elevation="0dp"
```

en el AppBarLayout dentro del XML, así se quita la sombra.